# Container transformed to fit, positioned absolute, still causing overflow as if not transformed

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, css-transforms

**Edit:** I had forgot to mention that I also had it positioned absolute. *Absolutely* sorry for that. Edits in content are in **bold**.

I have this container that I use for scaling its contents. I needed to scale things down evenly, and realized that I could use `transform` CSS attribute for my convenience.

The result is good, the contents are scaled and placed nicely. The problem is, I get overflow on the `body` element, caused by the container element. It is not crossing the window borders, not when its transformed, **and is positioned absolute**. However, for some reason, my browser (Edge 16) decides to accommodate space for the element as if it was not transformed.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10000px; height: 10000px;
  border: solid 100px red;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(0.01);
}

.orange-box {
  width: 5000px; height: 2000px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='orange-box'>
</div>
```

I have tried it a couple of times on Chrome 64, I don't get overflows on body there. I do want to make use of this, though, and I want to have Edge support.

Is there a way to get around of this bug/issue? Is there, perhaps, a way to prevent specific elements from causing overflow, without completely hiding them? I don't want to `overflow: none` on the body, either, since the body might legitimately be overflowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encapsulated it all inside another container, positioned it as `relative`, transformed it with `translate(0)`. Transformation does nothing, but it is different than `none`, which is all I need to have a child positioned as `fixed` to respect its container's position: See [MDN/position/fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed)

Then, I have changed the positioning of our former container to `fixed`, which did what the `absolute` couldn't do on Edge 16, and removed the container from the document flow.

```css
.container-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  transform: translate(0);
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10000px; height: 10000px;
  border: solid 100px red;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(0.01);
}

.orange-box {
  width: 5000px; height: 2000px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-container'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='orange-box'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I positioned the container-container away from the top left, to show that the fixed child moves along with it, thanks to the `translate(0)` transform.

However, I didn't use this. I instead styled the container-container to have its `overflow` as `hidden` via CSS, and left everything as before. This works out only if the container-container has width and height set to be contained within the body, which was already the case in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug in Edge. At least, I see scrollbars in Chrome.

May be you can get around it placing the div far to the left and top (that don't stretch the body boundaries)

```css
.container {
    width: 10000px;
    height: 10000px;
    border: solid 100px red;
    transform: scale(0.01);
    top: -10095px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10095px;
    transform-origin: right bottom;
}

.orange-box {
  width: 5000px; height: 2000px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='orange-box'>
</div>
```

Comment: I am terribly sorry for missing a crucial information in my question: The container is actually **positioned as absolute** (edited my question accordingly). That should now make the scrollbars on your Chrome disappear (and also from mine). I may not move the container anywhere, since I need it exactly where it is, and at that exact size. It's function is to overlay the content beneath, with the content within.